# Sorting bibliography according to the order in .bib file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, sorting

Is it possible to sort the order of references using the order in the `.bib` file?

Comment: Could you provide some background information to this proposed approach? Eg, are the entries in the bib file sorted in some special, non-alphabetical way that needs to be preserved in the printed bibliography?

Comment: @Mico Yes you are right, I want to preserve the special ordering in bib file.

Comment: And *what* would this special ordering be? Is it based on the values of one or more fields (presumably not the `author` and `year` fields)? I ask these questions because, by design, BibTeX makes *no assumptions* about the ordering of the entries in the bib file(s), and it does not keep track of the input ordering. Hence, if the ordering of the entries does turn out to be important, one has to provide BibTeX with *some information* so that it can reconstruct that ordering during the sorting phase. Please start by indicating the sorting criteria, if any, that were applied to the bib file.

Comment: @Mico In such case, I would wish to ordering by authoring name, in reverse order. That is z comes before y, and so on.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that should work with *any* bib file, including one in which the entries have been sorted in reverse alphabetical order.

First, insert the following instruction at the top of the bib file:

```
@preamble{ "\newcommand{\noop}[1]{}" }
```

At first blush, the `\noop` instruction would seem to be pointless as it doesn't do anything with its argument. While this is true for the *LaTeX typesetting* run, it is *not* true for the *BibTeX sorting* phase. In fact, for the sorting phase of its job, BibTeX will replace `\noop{abc}` with `abc` and consider "`abc`" to be a part of the material that needs to be sorted alphabetically.

Second, assuming you have fewer than 26*26=676 entries in the bib file, insert `\noop{aa}`, `\noop{ab}`, ..., `\noop{az}`, `\noop{ba}`, `\noop{bb}`, ... instructions immediately (without space) before the surname of the first author in the `author` field of each and every entry:

```
@article{xyz,
   author  = "Dane \noop{aa}Miller and Jane Smith",
   ...
}
@book{123,
   author = "Jill \noop{ab}Anderson and Bill Carlson",
   ...
}
...
@techreport{johnson:2012,
   author = "\noop{ac}Johnson, Jimmy",
   ...
}
```

(If you have more than 676 entries, just expand the string length of the argument of `\noop` suitably, e.g, to `aaaa`, `aaab`, etc.)

Third, be sure to use a bibliography style file that sorts the bib entries alphabetically. The point of the `\noop` instructions should now be clear: For *sorting purposes*, the relevant surnames are "aaMiller", "abAnderson", and "acJohnson", and hence the three entries will be sorted in the same way they occur in the bib file (rather than Anderson followed by Johnson followed by Miller). Later, when LaTeX does its typesetting thing, it discards the `aa`, `ab`, etc prefixes, and the names will be typeset correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A solution by @egreg has been provided in this thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56640/204235

`\nocite{*}`can be added at the top of documents before any citations, your bibliography will be printed in the order of your `.bib` and you can still add citations that will use the numbering from your `.bib`.