# Author names do not appear in some items in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I am having an issue where some items (2 of 51 references) in my bibliography have the author names missing, and they are replaced by a blank. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHeBq.png) is an example. The entries for the above items in my .bib file are as follows:

```
@article{Evrard2017,
author = {Evrard, Fabien and Denner, Fabian and van Wachem, Berend},
doi = {10.1016/j.jcp.2017.09.034},
file = {:home/niran90/Documents/Mendeley//Evrard, Denner, van Wachem - 2017 - Estimation of curvature from volume fractions using parabolic reconstruction on two-dimensional unst.pdf:pdf},
issn = {10902716},
journal = {Journal of Computational Physics},
keywords = {Curvature,Height-function,Unstructured mesh,Volume fraction,Volume-of-fluid},
pages = {271--294},
publisher = {Elsevier Inc.},
title = {{Estimation of curvature from volume fractions using parabolic reconstruction on two-dimensional unstructured meshes}},
url = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2017.09.034},
volume = {351},
year = {2017}
}

@article{Evrard2020,
author = {Evrard, Fabien and Denner, Fabian and van Wachem, Berend},
doi = {10.1016/j.jcpx.2020.100060},
file = {:home/niran90/Documents/Mendeley/Evrard, Denner, van Wachem - 2020 - Height-function curvature estimation with arbitrary order on non-uniform Cartesian grids.pdf:pdf},
issn = {25900552},
journal = {Journal of Computational Physics: X},
keywords = {Arbitrary order,Curvature,Height-function,Non-uniform grid,Volume-of-fluid},
month = {jun},
number = {May},
pages = {100060},
publisher = {Elsevier Inc.},
title = {{Height-function curvature estimation with arbitrary order on non-uniform Cartesian grids}},
url = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcpx.2020.100060 https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S2590055220300123},
volume = {7},
year = {2020}
}
```

I exported the .bib file from Mendeley, and I import it into my main.tex file using:

```
\usepackage[square,comma,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{siam}
\bibliography{Mendeley.bib}
\end{document}
```

Interestingly, this only occurs for some bibliography styles. I would like to use siam though. Can someone advise me on this?

Comment: Some bibliography styles replace the author name by a line if it is the same as the previous author in the list, i.e., if you cite multiple papers by the same author(s). This is a design choice in the style, if you don't want this then the easiest solution is to choose another style that always prints the names.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29381/is-it-normal-for-bibtex-to-replace-similar-author-names-with, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74301/name-of-authors-in-the-references-is-replaced-by-a-dashed-line, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540219/why-am-i-getting-a-blank-author-in-bibtex-when-it-exists for some workarounds.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much for the info!