# Biber: custom sort order

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm writing a paper where I cite several undated texts by the same author (as well as their published work) and I would like them to have them appear in my bibliography based on the order they are believed to be written in. The .bib entries for the undated texts have ranges of years as their year entry. Since these are not integers biber doesn't know how to sort them.  So I need a way to specify a custom sort.
My current bibliography setting are
`\usepackage[style=authoryear, maxnames=2, date=year, uniquename=false, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}`

I think biber's anyt sort option could work but I can't find anything in the documentation about what the alphabetic label is, so an explanation of how that works might solve the problem.

The \noop (empty operation) solution given here doesn't work [Sorting bibliography according to the order in .bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203035/sorting-bibliography-according-to-the-order-in-bib-file). Because putting \noop in the author field makes biber treat them as distinct authors and putting it in the year field doesn't fix the fact that the whole entry for that field is not an integer so biber can't sort it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sortyear` to give the "presumed" year of publication. Note that `sortyear` should be an integer. (If you have date ranges, you should use the `date` field instead of the `year` field, since `date` can deal with ISO date ranges, e.g. `date = {1956/1959},`. Of course this may not immediately help with sorting if you have several works from the same range with different presumed publication dates.)

If you have several works from the same presumed year, `sortyear` will probably have to work together with `sorttitle`.

---

The `a` in `anyt` refers to the alphabetic citation label generated for `style=alphabetic,`. I don't think it is particularly helpful here.